# Camera Calibration using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a project in wich I have to use OpneCV to get the camera matrix, I run the OpenCV sample project, my question is hwo can check if the save data is correct or not ?? because for my first example her eis what I get:

```
<Camera_Matrix type_id="opencv-matrix">
<rows>3</rows>
<cols>3</cols>
```

d

4.0608614269653586e+001 0. 3.1950000000000000e+002 0.
    4.0608614269653586e+001 2.3950000000000000e+002 0. 0. 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in checking if your data are saved correctly, read your matrix back. This can be done with FileStorage class openCV. Here is an example of [write](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_xml_yaml_persistence.html?highlight=filestor#write) and you can find a read function on the same page.

If you want to know whether your matrix makes sense first use a sanity check. A simplest camera matrix consist of these entries:

[ fx, 0, cx; 0, fy, cy; 0, 0, 1]

where fx=fy if the pixels are square and cx=w/2 and cy=h/2 approximately. It seems that your matrix may be correct given that you used 640x480 image and your focal length is about 40 pixels. However, the latter looks suspicious: the field of view (FOV) of your camera can be calculated from this formula: tan2(FOV/2) = w*0.5 / f = 320/40= 80, from which it follows FOV = 180deg;
This can happen only if you use a very wide angle length (so called fish-eye). If this is not the case check your calibration procedure. What code did you use?

Answer (score 0):

your matrix looks okay, 3x3 Matrix.

When you say save data, You want to record a video ?

But I refer you to the Q&A of openCV.

http://answers.opencv.org/questions/

Ask your question on this forum.